# Why does my 8x8 X and 0 break line after each output

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm trying to create an 8x8 Alternating X and 0 that switches position in the next line

```
X0X0X0X0
0X0X0X0X
X0X0X0X0
0X0X0X0X
X0X0X0X0
0X0X0X0X
X0X0X0X0
0X0X0X0X
```

Instead my return is this

```
X
0
X
0
X
0
X
0

0
X
...
```

What is causing the code to always break line if I'm not using the \n statement

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
            if (row % 2 == 0) {
                for (int row1 = 0; row1 < 8; row1++) {
                    if (row1 % 2 == 0) {
                        System.out.println("X");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("0");
                    }

                }
                System.out.println("\n");
            } else {
                for (int row2 = 0; row2 < 8; row2++) {
                    if (row2 % 2 == 0) {
                        System.out.println("0");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("X");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ln` in `println` stands for *line*.

Comment: This solves my issue, using it without ln fixes the issue, thank you.